# Disambiguate Unanswered Quick Link

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, unanswered-questions, question-lists

Can we disambiguate the term "Unanswered"? It would be nice to see all the questions in a tag or series of questions that are truly UNanswered versus Not Accepted. Right now, if you select the Unanswered link, it shows you questions with answers and without answers. To me, that's counter-intuitive. I am proposing to break it up into two links: `Unanswered` and `Not Accepted`.

Comment: I think this has been asked before to separate empty from Not accepted answers. Still a great idea

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bug]+answers%3A0 ?

Answer (score 4):

The wording of the Unanswered tab is clear if you angle your eyes toward the right of screen.

> [image: all hail the banner of non-upvoted!]

You'll see a note about what questions are showing up here:

> questions with **no upvoted answers**

If you want to see all questions with no answers, use the search:

> [answers:0](https://superuser.com/search?q=answers:0)

If you want to see those that have not accepted an answer:

> [hasaccepted:0](https://serverfault.com/search?q=hasaccepted:0)

Mix and combine with tags in square brackets (`[]`) to suit your [flavour of search](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: What happened to the dude's leg?

Comment: @rchern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Can-can.

Comment: Thats an awesome screenshot now.

Comment: Gotcha. Why not make a hotlink?